# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to dele a user account from to do list app, but unfortunately I get an error. I Get this error when trying to delete a user from to do list app

This is my code.

```
server.delete("/user/delete", async function(req, res){
  const newDeleteUser = new user(req.body.username, req.body.password);
  await newDeleteUser.delete();
  res.status(200).json(newDeleteUser).end();
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

```
class User {
    constructor(username, password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
            .update(password)
            .digest('hex');
        this.valid = false;
    }

    async delete(){
        try{
            let response = await database.deleteUser(this.username,this.password);
            return response;
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
    

}
```

```
async deleteUser(username, password){
        const client = new pg.Client(this.credentials);
        let results = null;
        try{
            await client.connect();
            results = await client.query('DELETE FROM "public"."users" WHERE username = $1 and password = $2 RETURNING *;', [username, password]);
            client.end();
        }catch(err){
            client.end();
            console.log(err);
            results = err;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Please help